# Make is not recognizing my library!

Tags: compilation, makefile, libraries, c++, g++

I am trying to create a program in C++ that utilizes the rudeconfig library.

I run make, and get this:

```
g++ -o Homework5_executable helloworld.o -lrudeconfig -L/home/j/je/jea160530/hw5/libs

/bin/ld: cannot find -lrudeconfig
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Homework5_executable] Error 1
```

I know this is happening because make is not recognizing the rudeconfig library, however I have followed the instructions on the rudeconfig site for install correctly.

Here is the code:

Makefile

```
#
# Set up info for C++ implicit rule
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
CPPFLAGS = -I/home/012/j/je/jea160530/hw5/include 

#
# Set up any Linker Flags
LDFLAGS = -L/home/012/j/je/jea160530/hw5/libs

#
# Set up libraries needer for compilation
LDLIBS = -lrudeconfig

#
# We choose the project name. This is used in building the file name for the backup target
PROJECTNAME = JesseAlotto_Homework5

#
# We choose the source files to include and name the output
SRCS = helloworld.cc

#
# We choose the name of the executable to be created
EXEC = Homework5_executable

#
# NORMALLY DON'T NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW HERE
# =================================================
#
OBJS = $(SRCS:cc=o)

all: $(EXEC)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) *.d *~ \#* $(EXEC)

Makefile: $(SRCS:.cc=.d)





# Pattern for .d files.
# =====================

%.d:%.cc
    @echo Updating .d Dependency File
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
    $(CXX) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
    rm -f $@.$$$$



# This is a rule to link the files. Pretty standard
# ================================================


$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
    @echo Program compiled succesfully!

#
# Backup Target
# =============

backup: clean
    @mkdir -p ~/backups; chmod 700 ~/backups
    @$(eval CURDIRNAME := $(bash pwd))
    @$(eval MKBKUPNAME := ~/backups/$(PROJECTNAME)-$(shell date +'%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S').tar.gz)
    @echo
    @echo Writing Backup file to: $(MKBKUPNAME)
    @echo
    @tar -zcvf $(MKBKUPNAME) ./$(CURDIRNAME)
    @chmod 600 $(MKBKUPNAME)
    @echo
    @echo Done!
    #
# Include the dependency files
# ============================

-include $(SRCS:.cc=.d)
```

helloworld.cc

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <tclap/CmdLine.h>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <rude/config.h>

using namespace rude;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::string nextLine;
    std::map<int, std::string> optionMap;


try{
    std::cout << "hello world!";


    //Command Line Variable
    TCLAP::CmdLine cmd("CS3377.002 Program 5", ' ', "1.0");

    //Switch Args
    TCLAP::SwitchArg daemonSwitch("d", "daemon", "Run in daemon mode (forks to run as a daemon).", cmd, false);

    //Unlabeled Value Args
    TCLAP::UnlabeledValueArg<std::string> infileArg("infile", "The name of the configuration file. Defaults to cs3376dirmond.conf", true, "cs3376dirmond.conf", "config filename", false);

    //Add leftover flags to cmdLine object
    cmd.add(infileArg);

    //Parse the command line
    cmd.parse(argc, argv);

    //Create an enumeratedlist for the mapping
    enum flags {DAEMON, INFILE};

    //Map keys and values to map

    if (daemonSwitch.getValue()){
        optionMap[DAEMON] = "1";
    }
    else{
        optionMap[DAEMON] = "0";
    }
    optionMap[INFILE] = infileArg.getValue();

    //Load input file
    std::ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(optionMap[INFILE].c_str(), std::ios::in);

    if(!inputFile){
        std::cerr << "Error: no input file" << std::endl;
    }







    //============================================PARSE CONFIGURATION FILE==========================
    Config config;
    config.load("cs3376dirmond.conf");





    //==============================================================================================


    inputFile.close();
    return 0;

} catch (TCLAP::ArgException &e) //catch any exceptions
{ std::cerr << "error: " << e.error() << " for arg " << e.argId() << std::endl;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by this command:

```
g++ -o Homework5_executable helloworld.o -lrudeconfig -L/home/j/je/jea160530/hw5/libs
```

not by `make` itself.

The error means that the linker isn’t finding `librudeconfig.so` in the library search path. From your comments, it turns out the library is named `rudeconfig.so` instead, so you need to specify

```
LDLIBS = -l:rudeconfig.so
```

instead of `-lrudeconfig` (which always expands to `librudeconfig.so` or `librudeconfig.a`).

Ideally, the library should be installed as `librudeconfig.so`...

Comment: Unfortunately, swapping those two options does not fix my problem. Same error as before. I have verified that the path name for the library is correct by referencing it with the output of the pwd command.

Comment: Hmm... What does `ls -l /home/j/je/jea160530/hw5/libs/librudeconfig.so` show?

Comment: pwd displays

/home/012/j/je/jea160530/hw5

when I type 

ls -l /home/012/j/je/jea160530/hw5/libs it shows the following contents

"rudeconfig.lib"

"rudeconfig.so -> ./rudeconfig.so.2.1"


"rudeconfig.so.2.1"

Comment: Well that’s weird, the library should be called `librudeconfig...`, not just `rudeconfig...`.

Comment: @StephenKitt From the [linker manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options), "-L searchir  ... All -L options apply to all -l options, regardless of the order in which the options appear."

Comment: Ah yes @Mike, thanks; I’ve updated my answer to address the real problem.

Comment: After renaming rudeconfig.so to librudeconfig.so, I get this error. "Skipping incompatible /path/name/here/librudeconfig.so when searching for -lrudeconfig"

So now I know that the directory is being recognized, it has to be some problem with the library itself?

Comment: Looks like it... Could you edit your question to show the output of `g++ -v` and `file /home/012/j/je/jea160530/hw5/libs/rudeconfig.so.2.1`?

Comment: Got it working! Apparently I was using an outdated version. Installed the newest version, used the include configuration tools, and now I'm compiling succesfully. Thank you for your help!